# watchOS, WCSession activationDidCompleteWith "activated", yet is not reachable

Tags: ios, swift

On start up I make the watch send a message to the iOS device to let the app know its ready to receive updated data. Sometimes this code works fine, sometimes it doesn't.

It often fails with the following debug output:

```
16:12:15.150|WatchSessionManager|WC Session activated with state: 2 (0 - notActivated, 1 - inactive, 2 - activated)
16:12:15.194|WatchSessionManager|Not reachable
```

Based on what I've read in the Apple docs once the connection is activated, you can send live messages like this. Why is it failing when the connection has been activated?

Thanks.

For reference, the below code is being called in ExtensionDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.startSession() //connect to iPhone
}
```

The code:

```
func startSession() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session  = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("WC Session activation failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    debug.log(tag: "WatchSessionManager", content: "WC Session activated with state: \(activationState.rawValue) (0 - notActivated, 1 - inactive, 2 - activated)")

    if WCSession.default().isReachable {
        debug.log(tag: "WatchSessionManager", content: "Requesting")
        let message = ["request": "masterList"]

        WCSession.default().sendMessage(message, replyHandler: { (replyDict) -> Void in
            //do stuff

        }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
            self.debug.log(tag: "WatchSessionManager", content: "Send to iOS app failed with error \(error)")
        })
    }
    else {
        debug.log(tag: "WatchSessionManager", content: "Not reachable")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check these terms? https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-isreachable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those in a similar boat, I never ended up finding the cause of this problem. However, as a bit of a workaround, I looped up my start session function, to attempt a new connection every couple of seconds when a connection has failed, and it needs to send/receive data. The second connection attempt was basically successful every time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check `activationState` to be `active` and `isReachable` is `true` before sending any messages between watch and phone. As mentioned above in the comment check docs here - https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-isreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are reasons the phone might not be reachable even with an activated WCSession: it's not in range of the watch, bluetooth is off, or the phone [hasn't been unlocked since its last reboot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1628256-iosdeviceneedsunlockafterrebootf?language=objc).

Also see the [Apple docs for isReachable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-reachable?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

After WCSession is activated it takes sometime for the device to be reachable. So I tried using KVO to watch for .isReachable to change to true and then I send the message. It works every time. I have added the code below. I know I am probably too late but it may help someone in future :)

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
        self.session.delegate = self
        self.session.activate()
    } else {
        self.userDataPublisher.send(completion: .failure(.watchUnsupported))
    }
    session.publisher(for: \.isReachable)
        .sink { isReachable in
            if isReachable {
                self.sendMessage()
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using sessionReachabilityDidChange(_ session: WCSession) WCSessionDelegate method.